# Getting the number of occurrences from a CSV

Tags: python, sorting, csv, count, counter

**Output Goal**:

```
Apache 2.0.44 (Linux) - 2
Cisco IOS - 4
Linux Kernel 2.4.20 - 1
Microsoft IIS 5.0 < 5.1 - 2
```

**Current Output m.group(1):**

```
Apache 2.0.44 (Linux)
Apache 2.0.44 (Linux)
Cisco IOS
Cisco IOS
Cisco IOS
Cisco IOS
Linux Kernel 2.4.20
Microsoft IIS 5.0 < 5.1
Microsoft IIS 5.0 < 5.1
```

I have a CSV file, I'm successfully grabbing output from the 3rd column (called title) and removing some unwanted content from it (I only want the content from that one row, and want to remove everything after a "-")

```
import sys, csv, operator, re

reader = csv.reader(open("test.csv"), delimiter=",")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=False)
for id, path, title, date, author, platform, type, port in sortedlist:
     m = re.search(r'^(.*?)\-.*', title)
     if m:
        print m.group(1)
```

Now I need the content of `m.group(1)` to remove the repeats but display a number of the times it occurs. Using `Counter` counts every single letter of each item...I'm at a loss.

Comment: You mean you only want the content from that one **column**, don't you?

Comment: Based on your comments under a couple of the answers, it seem you're leave some important detail about how you want different items with slightly different titles to be counted. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing m.group(1), append it to a list of results. Then use `Counter` with that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, csv, operator, re, collections

result = collections.Counter()
reader = csv.reader(open("test.csv"), delimiter=",")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=False)
for id, path, title, date, author, platform, type, port in sortedlist:
     m = re.search(r'^(.*?)\-.*', title)
     if m:
        result[m.group(1)] += 1

for group, count in results.items():
    print('{} - {}'.format(group, count))
```

Comment: collection.Counter() instead of Counter()

Comment: Ok, this is super close. However it outputs "1" after every result, when some of them should have more than one.

Comment: I THINK this is because the original input is different for every line... so I might have a line that says "Cisco IOS - something" and another line that says "Cisco IOS - somethingElse". The regex makes the two lines look the same, but originally they are slightly different. Thanks for the help so far, let me know if you have any ideas how to approach this....

Comment: @M3G4N: So you would want those two Cisco lines counted separately, but when they're displayed with their count, they'll look like the same thing was counted as two separate (which isn't true because they really have different titles in the input, but that's not displayed).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to @Raymond Hettinger's (he beat me posting an answer), but I also modified the regex and made a few other modifications:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv
import operator
import re
import sys

counter = Counter()
with open("occurrences.csv", 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")]
    for id, path, title, date, author, platform, type, port in data:
        m = re.search(r'^(.*?)\s*\-.*', title)
        title = m.group(1) if m else title
        counter.update([title])

for title, count in sorted(counter.items()):
    print('{} - {}'.format(title, count))
```

Comment: Super close to what I need but like the post from @Raymond Hettinger it outputs "1" after every line, some of them should be more... I left more info in his comment. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: So if you had two titles that vary only by what comes after the "-" character, what exactly would the output (count) for them be since the difference in the title between them would not be displayed? If it's two separate lines with a count of 1, how would one tell them apart in the output? It would also be super useful if you would edit your question and add some sample input to it—be sure to include some that are only different in what follows the "-" character in the title.